# How do I specify output file for running emacs in batch mode?

Tags: emacs, verilog

I am running emacs with Verilog-mode in batch mode. Normally, it overwrites the source file, but I would like to preserve the source file and write the output to a different file. I am trying to put this into a makefile flow, so I need separate input and output files.

My command line:

```
emacs --batch xyz.auto.sv -f verilog-diff-auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
emacs --batch xyz.auto.sv -f verilog-diff-auto --eval '(write-file "output.sv")'
```

That should read the input file into a buffer, do whatever `verilog-diff-auto` is supposed to do and then save the modified buffer to the output file.

Comment: This successfully creates output.sv, but it also still modifies xyz.auto.sv.  How do we get it to not touch the input?

Comment: Well, that may be the fault of `verilog-diff-auto` (I have no idea what it does). A short web search uncovered `verilog-batch-diff-auto`. Maybe that actually does what you want?

Comment: Ah, I found another variation that does what I want, in combination with the write-file flag: emacs --batch xyz.auto.sv -f verilog-auto --eval '(write-file "output.sv")'

Comment: Just a nit: `write-file` is a *function*, not a flag.